# Force Apache Server/Tomcat to ignore Transfer-Encoding

Tags: apache, request-smuggling

I am trying to reproduce [HTTP request smuggling](https://portswigger.net/web-security/request-smuggling) using an Apache HTTP Server as a reverse proxy (using mod_proxy) and a Tomcat Server in the back-end.

Is it possible to force either Apache Server or Tomcat to ignore Transfer-Encoding in requests (and only use Content-Length)? Or is request smuggling simply not possible with this configuration?